# "File" exists or not

Tags: linux, ls

ls -il

```
ls: cannot access éaj/p╬σt.ó∙e: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access éaj/p╬σt.ó∙e: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access é@j/p╠φt.│∙N: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access é@j/p╠φt.│∙N: No such file or directory
total 55456
    ? -????????? ? ?    ?           ?                ? éaj/p╬σt.ó∙e
    ? -????????? ? ?    ?           ?                ? éaj/p╬σt.ó∙e
    ? -????????? ? ?    ?           ?                ? é@j/p╠φt.│∙N
    ? -????????? ? ?    ?           ?                ? é@j/p╠φt.│∙N
```

and when i use  to show these files, i get the info:

```
p╬σt.ó∙e
p╠φt.│∙N
```

Please, where do these files or somethings others exist.
Or what makes them show here.

Answer (score 3):

Your filesystem is borked. Unmount it and run `fsck` against the volume.

Comment: thanks for your answer, howerver, i have formated my sd-card and  already rebuilded it, so i can't confirm whether it works and sorry for that. 've read the somrthing about fsck, and agree with you. Thanks again.